# Getting "Error parsing arguments for import " while trying to importing tables from postgres to HDFS?

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, sqoop

I am using the following command to import the database :

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0:5432/toptal?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory' -P \
--username 'capacityprediction_user'\
--table 'raw_hd' \
--target-dir '/home/raw_hd'
```

I am new to Hadoop ,I have followed the below link 
https://www.toptal.com/database/hdfs-tutorial-data-migration-from-postgresql

Error I am getting is :

```
17/09/14 05:32:24 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
17/09/14 05:32:24 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: raw_hd
17/09/14 05:32:24 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --target-dir
17/09/14 05:32:24 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: /home/raw_hd
```

Comment: Try this: `sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0:5432/toptal?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory' \
--username 'capacityprediction_user' -P \
--table 'raw_hd' \
--target-dir '/home/raw_hd'`

Comment: @MohammadYaseen still getting the same eroor .

Comment: Your command is working fine for me, you might have some problem in the way your are copying the command (if you are copying it). Try something like (without the \ characters, this should go in single line) `sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0:5432/toptal?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory' --username 'test_user' -P --table 'some_table' --target-dir '/path/to/dir'`